# Internet Explorer - width as a percentage is being rounded to two decimal places?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm grabbing a value from a data attribute on my page, and passing this to the width of an element. In Chrome this works as expected, the width returns as:

```
data-width="1.2359103215" style="width: 1.2359103215%"
```

however in IE11 it always rounds down to two decimal places:

```
data-width="1.2359103215" style="width: 1.24%"
```

Is there any way to pass this to the width in IE and have it take the exact same value?

Comment: Probably not, but worth remembering that the third decimal place will only matter if your element is more than 10000px wide.

Comment: @BenWest I need about 6 decimal places, as this forms part of a carousel and these %'s determine how precise the carousel animates to each slide. In this case I do need the few decimal places.

Comment: @RebeccaO'Sullivan Why not just use pixel-accurate values then?

Comment: @Bergi it needs to be responsive and the carousel calculations are in percentages also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rejigged the carousel structure to have the slide widths as 100% of a larger fixed pixel width, which becomes a vw value at a certain window width.